# Can I trust an SSD drive which failed suddenly

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, 64-bit

Recently I had a 250GB SSD, Windows 10 system drive fail suddenly.  When I looked for it using Acronis Disk Director it listed it a undefined and that no data could be recovered from it.

OK, now I have replaced it with a new SSD drive and, as an experiment, I mounted the old drive in a USB external box.  Windows 10 Disk Manager saw the drive but said it needed to be initialized.  I did that and then it formatted without any errors.

SO my question, is this drive worth keeping and using? What could have caused the initial failure?

Thanks....RDK

Comment: I'd never trust a failed drive. But this subject is highly subject to opinion, as there's no real way to tell, for any single drive, what's happened without physically having the drive and testing it in various ways. Therefore I'm voting to close this question as opinion based.

Comment: Drives that experience sudden failures are almost always inevitably on the road to complete failure fairly soon. Take the hint. =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were an HDD, I'd tell you no, it's a bad interface board, don't waste your time and data.   SSD are a little harder to predict, since they have no moving parts and the interface components are typically directly on the same board that handles r/w/x for your data.

If you used a different SATA cable on the new drive, the whole problem may have actually been a cable problem and both drives may be fine. Because the external unit detected the drive was corrupt, though, I wouldn't trust the drive to remain stable.  Use it to install unimportant apps, not to save any data.

Personally, I'd just use it in something old I don't care about because I have some old parts sitting around and sometimes one gets bored on a Sunday afternoon.  I wouldn't put this in anything regular-use, because I've seen a drive that blows its interface board or components start murdering any SATA port it docks with after.